# Pyspark RDD .filter() with wildcard

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I have an Pyspark RDD with a text column  that I want to use as a a filter, so I have the following code:

```
table2 = table1.filter(lambda x: x[12] == "*TEXT*")
```

To problem is... As you see I'm using the `*` to try to tell him to interpret that as a wildcard, but no success.
Anyone has a help no that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The lambda function is pure python, so something like below would work

```
table2 = table1.filter(lambda x: "TEXT" in x[12])
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
In addition, do you know if I can filter this text in more than one column? I was thinking in something like this `table2 = table1.filter(lambda x: "TEXT" in (x[7] or x[12]))`

Comment: Close. I think `"TEXT" in x[7] or "TEXT" in x[12]`  would be the easiest to read. You could do a string concatenation hack like  `"TEXT" in x[7] + "_" + x[12]`

Comment: Worked as a charm, you are the best David, thank you for such quick response.

Comment: Do you know what's the negation of this? table1.filter(lambda x: "TEXT" not in x[12])?

Comment: `lambda x: "TEXT" not in x[12]`. The lambda function is pure python. So you can play around without using spark. Eg `"text" not in "texta"` runs in python and returns `False` @annunarcist